# Update SpringXD module count after deployment

Tags: spring-xd

I did not find a way to update a module count once a stream is deployed. I wonder if it is currently a supported feature?

I find it hard to believe that the only way to do it is by un-deploying and re-deploying the stream as it actually mean downtime in a production environment, when all I want is to scale-up.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Module count can not be modified once the stream is deployed. The obvious reason is not to override the stream [partitioning](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#stream-partitioning) that is established.  If you want dynamic scaling, you can specify module.*.count=0 and any new container that matches the deployment criteria would have these modules deployed. Note that this works in case of [direct binding](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#direct-binding) when all the modules are co-located on the same container.

Comment: I am aware to this solution, but using this syntax I cannot really take leverage on spring-xd cluster mode.